# How to open JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener

I have to program that takes ip Addresses from a file and outputs the country its in onto a JTable. I have no errors but when i click the button the JTable doesn't open up. How do i make the JTable open up?

```
package org.koushik.javabrains;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import net.webservicex.GeoIP;
import net.webservicex.GeoIPService;
import net.webservicex.GeoIPServiceSoap;

public class IPLocationFinder {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
    filechooser.setVisible(false);
    final JTable jt;
    final String[] columns= {"IP address","Country"};
    final String[][] data = {{}};
    final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
    jt = new JTable(model);
    jt.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(450, 60));
    jt.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane();
    jt.add(jps);
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Start");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
    panel.add(b1, c);
    frame.setBounds(400,150,600,200);

     ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {



            new IPLocationFinder();
              BufferedReader inputStream = null;

              try {
                  inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/IP Addresses/ip.txt"));
                  String l;
                  try {
                    while ((l = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                          String ipAddress = l;
                          GeoIPService ipService = new GeoIPService();
                          GeoIPServiceSoap geoIPServiceSoap = ipService.getGeoIPServiceSoap();
                          GeoIP geoIp = geoIPServiceSoap.getGeoIP(ipAddress);
                          model.addRow(new String[][]{{"Column 1", geoIp.getCountryName()}});
                      }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                  if (inputStream != null) {
                      try {
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
            }
        }
     };
     b1.addActionListener(actionListener);
}
}
```

Comment: Add `JTable` inside `JScrollPane` not opposite. `jt.add(jps);` not correct instead it should be like `JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(jt);` or call `jps.setView(jt)`

Comment: complementing @Braj's comment, add `JScrollPane` to the `JPanel` in order to show the table

Comment: Im still not getting the table. I added what you guys said but no change

Comment: also avoid using `null` layout, instead try a [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. You never add the `JTable` to your panel.
2. You're adding a `JScrollPane` to your `JTable` when it should be the other way around. The `JScrollPane` should have its view set to the scrollable component, which in this case is the `JTable`. Otherwise, as your table's rows increase, the elements above it are simply going to be pushed up.
3. You've added an empty row to your table by saying `final String[][] data = { {} };`. When you start adding rows, you'll have a blank row to start. Therefore, you should remove the inner curly braces.
4. You should be aware that your JTable data is being prescribed as a 2D String array and although you're technically adding the data correctly, it's going to show up as an address in your first column:

[image: JTable column with garbage being populated in the first column]

To fix the above issue, change your `addRow` data to a 2D array such as `model.addRow(new String[] { "Column 1", "Country 1" });`

Below is a simplified, corrected version:

[image: Fixed JTable with working addition of information]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class IPLocationFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] columns = { "IP address", "Country" };
        final String[][] data = {};
        final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
        final JTable jt = new JTable(model);
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(jt);
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Start");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

        panel.add(b1, c);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(jps, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                model.addRow(new String[] { "Column 1", "Country 1" });
            }
        };
        b1.addActionListener(actionListener);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm gessing you're using a panel to show the jtable, however as you can notice, there's no a `panel.add(jt);` line.

So, go ahead and add that line inside the Action

**EDIT**

As @Braj comment, the jt must be added to the scroll. Then instead add the JTable, add the JScroll.

```
panel.add(jsp);
```

Comment: still not popping up the table